# Loop Code for Probability Distributions

Tags: octave

I'm trying to create a loop for a probability distribution. My initial condition is
$p_0 = (1, 0, 0, 0, 0)$,
$T$ = [0 1/3 1/3 1/3 0;
1/2 0 1/2 0 0;
1/3 1/3 0 1/3 0;
1/3 0 1/3 0 1/3;
0 0 0 1 0], (T is a five by five matrix)

and I am trying to find the probability distribution for the first 50 steps my using $p_n = p_0*T$ however I keep getting error messages. I'm not good with coding, this is what I have so far:

for n= 1:50;

p(n)= p(n-1)*(T);

end

Any code suggestions?

Comment: It would improve your Question to quote the error messages you got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```matlab
p0 = [1; 0; 0; 0; 0];

T = [0, 1/3, 1/3, 1/3, 0; 
     1/2, 0, 1/2, 0, 0; 
     1/3, 1/3, 0, 1/3, 0; 
     1/3, 0, 1/3, 0, 1/3; 
     0, 0, 0, 1, 0];

n_steps = 50;

p = p0;
for n = 1:n_steps
    p = T*p;
end
```

Comment: Notice that the OP uses the convention of a state row vector being right multiplied by the state transition matrix.